# LTC4421 Power Path Startup Issue

Tags: power

I am using LTC4421 power path controller to route the power between cable and battery in a robot. The output of the power path is feeding 2 dc-dc converters and 2 faulhaber motor drivers.

The power path controller fails to start without a significant delay in starting dc-dc converters and motor drivers. I added RC delay circuitry at the dc-dc controller enable pins. Now it starts fine as long as the motor drivers are unplugged. I cannot add a delay circuit into the motor drivers, which carry either linear or switching power converter for the internal logic.

[image]

I poked with a scope and what I observed is that LTC4421 indeed begins to drive power transistors after a power input is validated. Then voltage at the source (the output) of the power path transistors reaches a certain level (usually between 2-5V) LTC4421 stops raising gate voltage and just hangs in a half opened state failing to start the system.

I am using the same transistors as the [reference manual](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/LTC4421.pdf) suggests. The current measuring resistor is routed using Kelvin connections. There is a ground pour under the LTC4421 related circuitry. I do not see a point in a power path controller needing lots of additional delay circuitry, I assume I am doing something terribly wrong. I can add a picture of my layout upon request. Please Help.

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I have a near identical setup and am experiencing the same issue.
Many thanks!

Comment: Nope, I put this project away, but I would really like to know why it did not work..

Answer (score 1):

I believe you did not put a pull up on notFault 1/2, and this is why it doesn't startup? notFault signals are open drain, and notDisable signals are schmitt trigger comparator inputs, meaning the notDisable is very likely = 0V, meaning it is disabling the LTC4421.

Try adding pull-ups to both Fault signals and see if it works.

Comment: There are (very) weak pull-ups: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvSee.png